# How to initialize Angular role based security?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, user-roles

I am following [this micosoft devblogs tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-implement-role-based-security/) for angular based security but I fail to understand how to initialize and keep the current permission of the user while he is using my angular app.

I simply created all the services and directives as explained in the tutorial, and even created the one service not explained in the tutorial like so:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthorizationDataService {

  getUserAuthUrl = 'User/GetUserAuthorization';

  constructor(@Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string, private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPermissions(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get<string[]>(this.baseUrl + this.getUserAuthUrl);
  }
}
```

So now when I set one of my divs as explained in the tutorial:

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-xl-1" [appDisableIfUnauthorized]="allowedPermission"> <!--UPDATE_FULL-->
      ...
</div>
```

It then fires the hasPermission method but the permissions field is just not initialized. So I then diverged from the tutorial and made it initialize in case it's undefined, so now my entire AuthorizationService class looks like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthGroup } from './Helpers/authorization.types';
import { AuthorizationDataService } from './authorization-data.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthorizationService {

  public permissions: Array<string>; // Store the actions for which this user has permission

  constructor(private authorizationDataService: AuthorizationDataService) { }

  hasPermission(authGroup: AuthGroup) {
    if (!this.permissions) {
      this.initializePermissions();
    }


    if (!!this.permissions && this.permissions.find(permission => { return permission === authGroup; })) {
      console.log("returns true");
      return true;
    }
    else {
      console.log("returns false");
      return false;
    }
    
  }

  // This method is called once and a list of permissions is stored in the permissions property
  initializePermissions() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      // Call API to retrieve the list of actions this user is permitted to perform. (Details not provided here.)
      // In this case, the method returns a Promise, but it could have been implemented as an Observable
      this.authorizationDataService.getPermissions()
        .subscribe(permissions => {
          this.permissions = permissions;
          resolve();
        })
    });
  }
}
```

I still keep getting false because the permissions field still doesnt get set in time because of the async here.

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly?

In another part I've done the routing example properly which works and even persists the permissions over to this div.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'newcustomer', component: NewCustomerComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], data: { auth: 'UPDATE_FULL' } } }
];
```

But when I tried calling he initializePermissions from AppModule or even the specific component where the div is, then I still dont get my expected behaviour.

```
export class AppModule {

  constructor(authorizationService: AuthorizationService) {
    authorizationService.initializePermissions();
  }
}
```

Of course I cannot rely on the user to do a routing action for the Roles to initialize, so I am at a loss here what to do?

My server side is .Net core 2.1 but I doubt that is of any importance here...

Edit 1. AuthGuardService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthorizationService } from './authorization.service';
import { AuthGroup } from './Helpers/authorization.types';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(protected router: Router,
    protected authorizationService: AuthorizationService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.hasRequiredPermission(route.data['auth']);
  }

  protected hasRequiredPermission(authGroup: AuthGroup): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    // If user’s permissions already retrieved from the API
    if (this.authorizationService.permissions) {
      if (authGroup) {
        return this.authorizationService.hasPermission(authGroup);
      } else {
        return this.authorizationService.hasPermission(null);
      }
    } else {
      // Otherwise, must request permissions from the API first
      const promise = new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
        this.authorizationService.initializePermissions()
          .then(() => {
            if (authGroup) {
              resolve(this.authorizationService.hasPermission(authGroup));
            } else {
              resolve(this.authorizationService.hasPermission(null));
            }
          }).catch(() => {
            resolve(false);
          });
      });
      return promise;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please add your AuthGuardService too?

Comment: @yash updated but its exactly the same to be honest

Comment: i can see many problems there... can you update this as stackblitz app? i could fix that for you on it

Comment: @yash, I've never used stackblitz but here it goes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-roles1
Its a very simplified version from what I have in my visual studio environment

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngx-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions), it is a great plugin to control permissions both on routing and view.